# VM cannot access port 25 while the host can

Tags: port, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Virtual machine running within the Virtual Box. And now I need to access the port 25 of a IP address from the VM. The thing is I am able to do the "telnet url 25" outside the VM in my host machine, but I just can not do it within the VM, the error is "name or service not known". For the host machine, I dont have any firewalls. Any idea why

Comment: Can you try running a `tracert` to see what hops the VM is taking to try and reach the IP and port, and possibly provide an output of that?

Comment: @X3074861X I just tried with the tracert6 command(can not find the tracert tool), and what it told me is "internal-smtp.xxxx.local port 33434: Name or service not known". May this will help! Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the virtual host is not configured to use the correct DNS server. Try using IP address instead of hostname.

Comment: @alvits Actually that`s the problem. The VM can not find the correct DNS to get the actual IP address. After I replace the url with IP address, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM can not resolve the URL cause a problem connection with the DNS server. After I replace the URL with a real IP address, it works!